# Function already defined is not accessible

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I'm using jQuery and in an external Javascript file called from the head, I have this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var localDb = null;
    function updateLocalStorage() {
        // localDb is set here
    }
} );
```

At the bottom of the page I start a new section with document.ready, however neither the `localDb` variable nor the `updateLocalStorage` function are accessible.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    updateLocalStorage();
} );
```

I get an error saying *"Uncaught ReferenceError: updateLocalStorage is not defined."* Why is this happening, and how do I access the previously defined function?

Comment: Did you try to set only one $(document).ready function? Put your definitions outside the ready function and see what happends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining updateLocalStorage as a local inner function that is only accessible from that ready handler. Also the case with the local variable localDb.

It'll work fine if you define the function and the variable outside of the `$(document).ready()` call;

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
$(document).ready(updateLocalStorage());
function updateLocalStorage() { // localDb is set here     }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because your wrapping a function within an anonymous function, therefore it's only available within that scope, what you should do is export the function to the global scope like so:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var localDb = null;

    function updateLocalStorage(){
        // localDb is set here
    }

    window.updateLocalStorage = updateLocalStorage;
});
```

you should not need to wrap the functions within a document ready, a better method to control the global scope is a self calling anonymous function to execute the required code.

```
(function(){

    var updateLocalStorage = function()
    {
    }

    $(document).ready(updateLocalStorage);

})();
```

Comment: Two problems here: `global.updateLocalStorage = ` will cause an error since global is undefined, I think you meant `window.updateLocalStorage = `. Second, there are no anonymous functions, that function is named updateLocalStorage, it is an inner function but not anonymous.

Comment: fixed, I have been programming like mad with node.js lately and I got a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be better off using

```
var updateLocalStorage;

$(document).ready( function() {
    var localDb = null;
    updateLocalStorage = function () {
        // localDb is set here
    }
} );
```

and then use it in your function later.